# Detect and Remove blank tableViewCell in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

I have two tableView running in my project.I have successfully passed data between two tableView and saved it as a tableView array into my second tableView using segue.I have another function to connect my second tableview using tabBar button. Everytime, when I press the tabBar button it creates a blank tableViewCell at indexPath:0. I can understand why is happening but I am not sure how to stop. My code below

**AppDelegate:**

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let defaultValues = ["NewArray": [String]()]
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: defaultValues)

    return true
    }
```

**MY Second VC**

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    newArray = defaults.array(forKey: "NewArray") as! [String]
   // newArray.append(newItem)
    newArray.insert(newItem, at: 0)
    defaults.set(newArray, forKey: "NewArray")
    self.favTableView?.reloadData()
   }
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Every time when `viewDidLoad` is called, a new item is inserted. The line seems to be blank if `newItem` is an empty string. You might reconsider your design to insert the item on demand.

Comment: @vadian can you elaborate more...Thanks

Comment: I wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the easiest solution is to check if `newItem` is not empty, because if the view is presented from the segue a (non-empty) string is passed to the `newItem` property.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
  newArray = defaults.array(forKey: "NewArray") as! [String]
  // newArray.append(newItem)
  if !newItem.isEmpty {
    newArray.insert(newItem, at: 0)
    defaults.set(newArray, forKey: "NewArray")
  }
  self.favTableView?.reloadData()
}
```